# I am unable to Register MATLAB as a COM Server

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio-2017, com, interop

I need your help.
I need to call a matlab function from c # visual studio, I added Matlab Application in the c # code references but it doesn't work.
So to do it I seem to have understood that you need to register matlab as a COM server.
I can't register matlab as a COM server.
My version of matlab is r2018a.
I tried to write in matlab, after logging in as administrator, the command:

```
! matlab -regsever
```

but nothing happens.
I tried to write:

```
[s, msg] = regmatlabserver
```

and I get:

```
s =
      0
msg =
   0 × 0 empty char array
```

can anyone tell me how to do it ??
Thank you so much

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in the first command, it should be `-regserver`

Comment: Are you running elevated when you try to register?